# Rails: Devise Logged In User List

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to produce a list of logged in users with [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)? I have searched high and low and cannot find one. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/plataformatec-devise/tOKU_jcWNp0